# Error deleting pointers in a vector

Tags: c++, pointers

I´m running into a problem with this piece of code:
First I create a class like this:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2> class MyClass
{
private:

    std::vector<T2> m_values;

    static const bool HAS_POINTER = std::is_pointer<T2>::value;
};
```

T2 could be, depending on the needs, either a type or a pointer.
My problem is when i try to release the pointers:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2> void MyClass<T1, T2>::Clear()
{
     if (HAS_POINTER)
     {
         for (int i = 0; i < m_values.size(); ++i)
             delete m_values[i];
     }
}
```

Here the compiler complains showing error C2541: Cannot delete objects that are not pointers
I know the compiler is right, but the problem is T2, in some cases, IS a pointer.
How do I deal with this?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Be like every standard container do nothing if it a pointer.  If the user wants it to be destroyed automagially they should use smart pointer.

Comment: You rather need to realize this with another `bool` template parameter, and a specialization.

Comment: If you are adamant about deleting the pointers then you will be to have two different classes to distinguish between pointers and objects.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Ohh right, this is not SFINAE, and there will be a compile-time error when instantiating for non-pointers. Good point!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Why another bool template parameter?

Comment: @ChristianHackl It's my standard approach. I didn't knew that partial specialization for pointers is possible, as you've given in your answer. Well done, THX for the enlightenment.

Answer (score 4):

You can [partially specialise templates](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization) for pointers. Here is a very simple example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T1, typename T2> class MyClass
{
public:
    std::vector<T2> m_values;

    void Clear()
    {
        std::cout << "no pointers\n";
    }
};

template <typename T1, typename T2> class MyClass<T1, T2*>
{
public:
    std::vector<T2*> m_values;

    void Clear()
    {
        std::cout << "pointers\n";

        for (int i = 0; i < m_values.size(); ++i)
            delete m_values[i];

    }
};

int main()
{
    MyClass<int, int> example;
    MyClass<int, int*> example2;
    example.Clear();
    example2.Clear();
}
```

Comment: I see. This will work nicely. Thank you for the quick answer

Comment: The only _possible_ downside with this solution is if `MyClass` is very large then a lot of code will be duplicated, correct? If so, then the pointer specific subset of functionality can be handled in a _helper_ class that is specialized for `T*` to reduce the duplication, right?

Comment: @JamesAdkison: Yes, that is the downside of the solution. But I'd rather solve it the other way round, by putting the common, pointer-neutral functionality into a common helper or private base class. As always, it depends.

Comment: Okay, I'd make sure the OP is aware of this maintenance issue (i.e., draw attention to it in your answer). +1